# Semiconductors light emission

Tags: visible-light, semiconductor-physics, photon-emission

Suppose a pure semiconductor, with a direct gap. If I apply a constant voltage to it the electrons will jump to the conduction band. So when I turn it off will it emite light?, because the electrons from the conduction band will deenergize releasing a photon.

How will the semiconductor's behaviour inside an alternating electric field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply a constant voltage to a piece of semiconductor, you will not get light out of it. All that will happen is that the electrons that are already in the conduction band will start drifting in the applied electric field, so you will get conduction and some heating.

In order to get effective recombination of electrons and holes (i.e. atoms that lack one electron), a pn-junction is needed, where the majority carriers in the n-region are electrons and the majority carriers in the p-region are holes. The pn-junction forms a depletion region where the drifting electrons and holes neutralize each other (recombination by thermal diffusion) until the charge imbalance builds up a potential barrier that prevents further movement of charges. The device becomes non-conductive at that point (a diode at 0V on its junction does not conduct except for a tiny thermal leakage current).

When you apply an external voltage on the junction that overcomes this potential difference, then you can get electrons from the n-region to drift into the p-region and holes from the p-region will drift into the n-region. Now you have the necessary conditions for recombination and significant amounts of light will be produced.